# Consulta com dois resultados de soma a partir de uma condição

Tags: sql-server, select, sum

Preciso realizar uma consulta em uma tabela de itens vendidos onde há um campo TipoItem que diz se o item é Produto(1) ou Serviço(2), eu gostaria que ele me trouxesse dois SUM's a partir de uma do campo Ocisubtot, onde se fosse produto(1) ele me trás um SUM e se for serviço(2) ele me traga outra coluna com SUM para serviços. Seria possível?

Exemplo:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Ocisubtot) AS 'Total Produto', 
  SUM(Ocisubtot) AS 'Total Serviço'
FROM Orvendalevel1
```

TipoItem tem 1 e 2 para condição.

Estou utilizando SQL Server, não sei se deve utilizar IF ou CASE neste caso e como aplicar.

Comment: Pivot com case  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846007/sql-query-to-pivot-a-column-using-case-when

Answer (score 0):

Isso seria possível utilizando sub-query para cada atributo, por exemplo

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT SUM(Ocisubtot) FROM Orvendalevel1 WHERE cod_product = 1
    ) AS 'Total Produto'
    (
        SELECT SUM(Ocisubtot) FROM Orvendalevel1 WHERE cod_product = 2
    ) AS 'Total Serviço'
;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava !!!